# Getting error while creating react native app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ubuntu, npm, create-react-app

I have installed Nodejs, Java, Python and android studio and installed create-react-native-appby following command

`npm install -g create-react-native-app`

after that I am running

`sudo create-react-native-app MyFirstNative`

but getting error

I have updated npm, expo-cli, etc and even using the command with `sudo` even then getting permission error

```
azad@azadhussain:/var/www/html/githubrepo$ sudo create-react-native-app MyFirstNative
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                             │
│   There is a new version of expo-cli available (2.17.2).    │
│   You are currently using expo-cli 2.17.1                   │
│   Run `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version   │
│                                                             │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
? Choose a template: expo-template-tabs
✔ Please enter a few initial configuration values.
  Read more: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/configuration/ · 100% completed
Extracting project files...
Customizing project...
Initialized a git repository.
Installing dependencies...
npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<2.6.5 is no longer maintained. Please, upgrade to core-js@3 or at least to actual version of core-js@2.
npm WARN deprecated kleur@2.0.2: Please upgrade to kleur@3 or migrate to 'ansi-colors' if you prefer the old syntax. Visit <https://github.com/lukeed/kleur/releases/tag/v3.0.0\> for migration path(s).
npm WARN deprecated left-pad@1.3.0: use String.prototype.padStart()
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/expo/react-native-maps.git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! fatal: failed to stat '/var/www/html/githubrepo/MyFirstNative': Permission denied
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/azad/.npm/_logs/2019-05-14T04_30_21_275Z-debug.log
npm exited with non-zero code: 1
Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
azad@azadhussain:/var/www/html/githubrepo$
```

[image]

Comment: There is a command if you are using expo.
`expo init AwesomeProject`

And also another for react-native-cli
`react-native init AwesomeProject`

Comment: Why `sudo`?? use try to use `create-react-native-app MyFirstNative` directly.

Comment: @Taym earlier I was trying without sudo after getting issue I used Sudo

Comment: Don't Use `sudo`! after using `sudo` you got this issue: `'/var/www/html/githubrepo/MyFirstNative': Permission denied`

Show me errors you got when you used sudo.

Comment: @Taym
With sudo error in question 

without sudo

$ create-react-native-app MyFirstNative
? Choose a template: (Use arrow keys)
  ----- Managed workflow -----
❯ blank         minimal dependencies to run and an empty root component  
  tabs          several example screens and tabs using react-navigation 
  ----- Bare workflow -----
  bare-minimum  minimal setup for using unimodules Uncaught Error { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/azad/.expo/state.json.3285620765']
  errno: -13,
  code: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: '/home/azad/.expo/state.json.3285620765' }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the permission of my .npm directory. I went to the npm global directory for me it was at

`/home/<user-name>`

I went to this directory by entering this command

`cd /home/<user-name>`

and then changed the permission of .npm folder by entering this command.

`sudo chmod -R 777 ".npm"`

It worked like a charm to me. But there is a security flaw with this i.e your global packages directory is accessible to all the levels.